# Connect Microsoft QnA Maker to Bot Framework

Tags: facebook, frameworks, bots

I have created a bot using QnA Maker and set up a FB App connected to our FB page and Microsoft Bot Framework.  However, something is missing.  How do I connect Microsoft QnA maker to Bot Framework?  (FWIW - the goal is a FB Messenger bot that answers FAQ regarding a non profit event).  Thanks

Comment: Best to simply use MS Azure and not Bot Framework.  Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly link the QnAMaker endpoint to FB. You first need to create a Bot Service using the QnAMaker template and then enable it on FB channel. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You nede to register on QNA maker and use the below code to get the response. no need to register on bot framework.

**Sample Request**

```
string responseString = string.Empty;

var query = “hi”; //User Query
var knowledgebaseId = “YOUR_KNOWLEDGE_BASE_ID”; // Use knowledge base id created.
var qnamakerSubscriptionKey = “YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY”; //Use subscription key assigned to you.

//Build the URI
Uri qnamakerUriBase = new Uri("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v1.0");
var builder = new UriBuilder($"{qnamakerUriBase}/knowledgebases/{knowledgebaseId}/generateAnswer");

//Add the question as part of the body
var postBody = $"{{\"question\": \"{query}\"}}";

//Send the POST request
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    //Set the encoding to UTF8
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    //Add the subscription key header
    client.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", qnamakerSubscriptionKey);
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    responseString = client.UploadString(builder.Uri, postBody);
}
```

**Sample Response**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 

private class QnAMakerResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The top answer found in the QnA Service.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The score in range [0, 100] corresponding to the top answer found in the QnA    Service.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "score")]
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
//De-serialize the response
QnAMakerResult response;
try
{
    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< QnAMakerResult >(responseString);
}
catch
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to deserialize QnA Maker response string.");
}
```

**Note: to get knowledge base id and subscription key you need to login and create a service**

do let me know in case you need any help

Answer (score 0):

In order to use QnAMaker in bot framework you may handle t when you get a none intent or some intent.
Simply add this in your LUIS dialog

```
[LuisModel("modelID", "SubscriptionKey")]
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneRes(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
            var qnadialog = new QnADialog();
            await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), AfterQnADialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    private async Task AfterQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var answerFound = await result;
        // handle after qna response
    }
}
```

And add this in your QnADialog

```
[Serializable]
[QnAMaker(authKey: "AuthKey", knowledgebaseId: "KnowledgebaseId", defaultMessage: "please rephrase, I could not understand.", scoreThreshold: 0.5, top: 1, endpointHostName: "https://yourAccount.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker")]
public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
{}
```

Done. 
Hope this will help